# Positioning/Sizing of a UIPopOver without an arrow

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I am having trouble with setting the size and position of a UIPopOver without an arrow.
What i am trying to do is to bring up a popover view on the top left of the iPad screen and also have the content size that i have set.

I get different content size for the popover when i use an arrow and when i not. When i use the following code:

```
    CGRect rec = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
    [self.displayOpPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rec inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

The result is:

[image: with arrow]

and when i do:
        [self.displayOpPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rec inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];

The result is :

[image: without arrow]

I have set 'use explicit size' for popovers in the storyboard (which is the size of the view when i have an arrow).
But the view somehow resizes itself when the arrow direction is 0.

Any suggestions as to how should i set the popover to the top left without an arrow.

Thanks !

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. I tried what you did and also tried setting either the frame of the content controller's view (self.pop.contentViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 500)) or setting the popover content size (self.pop.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 500)), and neither of them worked either.

Comment: see this it may help you 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338316/present-uipopovercontroller-in-same-position-with-changing-just-arrow-offset][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338316/present-uipopovercontroller-in-same-position-with-changing-just-arrow-offset