# How to specify position that popover controller's arrow points to

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uialertcontroller

It's well known that in order to present `UIAlertController` with `preferredStyle: .actionSheet`, it's a good practice to set an anchor using the next code:

```
 popover.sourceView = view
 popover.sourceRect = view.bounds
```

In my case, the view is `UIImageView`, it's size is 44x44, but its image (three vertical dots) is very thin (its size is 4x24). So the view is mostly transparent. As a result, popover "points" to empty space. (Note that I am using red color to show fully transparent area)

[image]

Ideally, popover's arrow should point to the central white dot. But I do not know how to achieve it. I tried to modify `sourceRect` as follows:

```
popover.sourceRect = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 1,
                            y: view.bounds.midY - 1,
                            width: 2,
                            height: 2)
```

but it points to the top white dot for some reason:

[image]

How can I make it pointing to the desired point?

Answer (score 1):

The `sourceRect` worked for me, i just used the y coordinates to position the arrow and it worked for me.

```
popover.sourceRect =  CGRect(x: 0, y: yourPosition, width: 0, height: 0)
```

You can also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338316/present-uipopovercontroller-in-same-position-with-changing-just-arrow-offset).